# How to solve this exponential equation for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have difficult to solve this this equation for x:
$$2*3^{x}+3^{2x-1}=12*(\frac{1}{2})^{(1-x)/2}-3$$
Thanks :)

Comment: show that $x=1$ is one solution

Comment: Let me [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2*3^{x}%2B3^{2x-1}%3D12*%28\frac{1}{2}%29^{%281-x%29%2F2}-3) it for you.

Comment: the other solution you will get by a numerical method

Comment: How I solve it ? without using wolfram Alpha

Answer (score 1):

by graph two function ,you can find root(s)
  $$f(x)=2*3^x+3^{2x-1}$$and $$g(x)=12\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1-x}{2}}-3 $$
[image]